# How to hidden above title links in accordion menu?

Tags: jquery

I am doing one accordion for now it's working fine but when i am clicking Title2 or Title1 next if i stepped to click Title3 only want to give Title link for this so no any sub links that's why i want to slide-up the above Titles.

fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cX68E/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#accordion> div').hide();
$('#accordion > h3').click(function() {
    if($(this).next('div').length) {
        $(this)
            .next('div')
            .slideToggle('fast')
            .siblings('div:visible')
            .slideUp('fast');
    } else {
         $(this)
            .siblings('div:visible')
            .slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/cX68E/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because the `.next()` returns empty when clicked on `title3`. So lets try doing the `slideUp` and then an `end` then `slideToggle`. See below,

```
$('#accordion> h3').click(function() {
  $(this)      
      .siblings('div:visible')
      .slideUp('fast')
      .end()
      .next('div')
      .slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cX68E/3/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't find the next div. Since there are no elements there, there are no siblings either.

So nothing to slide up.

You could add a div at the end or slide up first.

```
<h3>Title 3</h3>
    <div></div>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/a2qvU/